# How do you apply Lightning Design System CSS Styling to force:inputField?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, forceinputfield

I'm trying to use `force:inputField` so that I can get the picklist values on a picklist field of a custom object. If I preview the "**sampleCreateRecordApp.app**" the force:inputField does not have CSS styling, how do I apply Lightning Design System CSS to force:inputField? The below sample code does not appear to take the LDS stlying on the stand alone app?

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/#flavor-select

**sampleCreateRecordApp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:sampleCreateRecord/>

</aura:application>
```

**sampleCreateRecord.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="myobject" type="MyCustomObject__c" 
                               default="{ 'sobjectType': 'MyCustomObject__c' }"/>               


    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Select Label</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-select_container">
                <force:inputField aura:id="contactName" class="slds-select"
                                 value="{!v.myobject.inputPicklistField__c}"/> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```